# Wacom BambooFun can't change mode to relative

Tags: wacom, bamboo

I was recently trying to set up my Wacom BambooFun hard way - using `xsetwacom` commands.

I managed to do almost all set up, but when I try using:

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom BambooFun 6x8 Pad pad" "Mode" "Relative"
```

I get this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  XI_BadMode (invalid Mode parameter)
Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
Minor opcode of failed request:  5 (X_SetDeviceMode)
Mode id in failed request: 0x17
Serial number of failed request:  15
Current serial number in output stream:  15
```

Setting Mode to Absolute gives no output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just had the same issue and found the solution. It seems the "Relative" mode applies to the *stylus* or *pen*, not the *pad*. So for me, rather than:

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom BambooFun 6x8 Pad pad" Mode "Relative"
```

It was:

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom BambooFun 6x8 Pen stylus" Mode "Relative"
```

(notice `Pad pad` is swapped for `Pen stylus`. your particular values for these will be gotten from `xsetwacom --list devices`)

I hope this helps!